# Saving a pointer to heap created in the local area

Tags: c++, sfml, dynamic-memory-allocation

I made a "Planet" class and am trying to initialize a vector array based on this class in the client file of my project.

```
bool addPlanet(std::vector<Planet>& planets, std::string filePath)
{
    std::ifstream infile(filePath, std::ios_base::in);
 
    if (infile.fail()) {
        // File could not be opened
        return false;
    }
 
    std::string planetName, imagePath;
    float posX, posY, rotationZ, scaleX, scaleY;
    unsigned long long int planetMass;
 
    while (infile >> planetName >> posX >> posY >> rotationZ >> scaleX >> scaleY >> planetMass >> imagePath)
    {
        Planet* newPlanet = new Planet(sf::Vector2f(posX, posY), rotationZ, sf::Vector2f(scaleX, scaleY), planetMass, imagePath);
        
        planets.push_back(*newPlanet);
    }
 
    infile.close();
 
    return true;
}
```

But I can't figure out if the following piece of code is causing a memory leak:

```
while (infile >> planetName >> posX >> posY >> rotationZ >> scaleX >> scaleY >> planetMass >> imagePath)
{
    Planet* newPlanet = new Planet(sf::Vector2f(posX, posY), rotationZ, sf::Vector2f(scaleX, scaleY), planetMass, imagePath);
        
    planets.push_back(*newPlanet);
}
```

I think about it like this:

I allocate dynamic memory for a new instance of the "Planet" class. Using the push_back method — the vector 's internal iterator becomes a second pointer to the new instance. And when we exit the loop, there is still a pointer to the newly allocated heap in vector .

Do I understand everything correctly or am I just bad at reading the documentation?

Comment: `planets.push_back(*newPlanet)` means you are pushing a copy into the vector, not a pointer to the original object

Comment: Overall there seems to be no reason here to `new Planet` at all. Just create it with automatic storage duration e.g.: `Planet newPlanetsf::Vector2f(posX, posY), rotationZ, sf::Vector2f(scaleX, scaleY), planetMass, imagePath); planets.push_back(newPlanet);`

Comment: Also you can avoid a lot of such ownership concerns by using smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`)

Comment: @UnholySheep "Just create it with automatic storage duration."

Then, in the SFML render window, instead of a planet texture, I will see a white square.

The problem is that this class also contains a texture and a sprite. The sprite stores a pointer to the texture.

Comment: If creating the object with automatic storage duration instead of dynamic one causes such an issue then you have a deeper underlying problem. Just changing the storage duration should not be causing the texture to be lost

Comment: The vector's "internal iterator"? It looks like you're making some wild assumptions about how a vector is organized internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code creates a `Planet` object:

```
Planet* newPlanet = new Planet(sf::Vector2f(posX, posY), rotationZ, sf::Vector2f(scaleX, scaleY), planetMass, imagePath);
```

Then, it *copies* this object into the vector:

```
planets.push_back(*newPlanet);
```

But it doesn't release the memory corresponding to the original object. The vector only owns the copy, not the original `Planet` object.

---

You can simply solve this issue but not using `new` at all:

```
Planet newPlanet(sf::Vector2f(posX, posY), rotationZ, sf::Vector2f(scaleX, scaleY), planetMass, imagePath);
planets.push_back(std::move(newPlanet));
```

Here, it is the code block the one who owns the `newPlanet` object.

However, you may want to directly use [`std::vector::emplace_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) instead of `new` and `push_back()`:

```
planets.emplace_back(sf::Vector2f(posX, posY), rotationZ, sf::Vector2f(scaleX, scaleY), planetMass, imagePath);
```

This way, the vector acquires the ownership of the single `Planet` object that is created.

Comment: The result is ambiguous. Some instances display the sprite correctly, some just show white squares.

Comment: @Demexis This is very likely because the `sf::Sprite` objects are outliving the `sf::Texture` object they refer to.